# Relative Abelian Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

If $A$ is an abelian variety, we have an addition map $\mu:A\times A\to A$.

Now, suppose we have a relative abelian variety $\mathcal{A}\to B$, i.e. the morphism is flat and proper and for any $b\in B$, $\mathcal{A}_b$ is an abelian variety.

Can we define a morphism $\mu\colon\mathcal{A}\times_B\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}$ such that it restricts to the addition map on every fibre?

I think it should exist at least locally and I tried to prove its existence using base changes, but I failed.

Naively, I expect that the addition maps on the fibres glue together to form such a morphism but since I cannot find a rigorous argument I start thinking that maybe it only exists locally...?

To contextualise the question: I would like to define a relative Pontrjagin product on $\mathcal{A}$ and I was naively trying to understand if the easiest generalisation would work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. But if it is false (as you suspect, and I suspect it too), then your definition of relative abelian variety is not the good one : one should ask for the multiplication map to be a $B$-morphism $\mu:\mathcal{A}\times_B\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @Roland, thank you for the comment. So basically you are suggesting to add this hypothesis inside the definition of relative abelian variety, but unfortunately I start with a flat and proper fibration in abelian varieties and I'm just trying to understand if I can use such a tool. Anyway, can I can ask you why you suspect that the answer is negative (my suspect is just because I cannot prove, so not really enlightening)?

Comment: This is the usual definition of group scheme, or in fact any group object in a category, the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_B(\cdot,\mathcal{A})$ must be group-valued. This implies the existence of $\mu$. Now I know that there are flat morphisms such that each fibers are endowed with a group structure but which are not relative group, hence my suspicion, but abelian varieties are much more rigid, so I don't know...

Comment: @Roland, actually, I do not really want that $\mathcal{A}$ is a group over $B$, i.e. that the morphism $\mu$ satisfies the group axioms. It would be enough for me to have a regular morphism $\mu$ whose restriction on fibres is addition map. It sounds a weaker condition than the one stated by you, or am I wrong?

Comment: No it is not weaker, you can always write the group axioms with some diagrams, and to check that these diagrams commute, you can do it fiberwise. So the map is really what you need.

Comment: @Roland, I see...I agree with you then, it looks like it cannot be the case in general...I hope someone can come up with a definitive evidence (or proof). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this is true in general, but I suspect it is untrue.

However, if there is a section $e:A \to B$ such that $B_a$ is an abelian variety with identity section $e_a$ then it is true. In fact, if $A$ is connected, you only need a single fiber to be an Abelian variety. In chapter 6 of Mumford - 'Geometric Invariant Theory' one finds the following result (I am writing this from memory so there might be some details missing):

Theorem 6.14: Let $X \to S$ be a smooth proper morphism with section $e:S \to X$ where $S$ is connected and locally Noetherian. Assume that there is a geometric point $s \to S$ such that $X_s$ is an abelian variety with identity section $e_s$, then there is a (unique) multiplication $m:X \times_S X$ and $i:X \to X$ making $X/S$ into a group scheme with identity $e:S \to X$. Note that your morphism is indeed smooth since it is flat and has smooth fibers (you would need to add locally of finite presenation if your base scheme is non-Noetherian).

In general a proper smooth group scheme with connected geometric) fibers is called an Abelian scheme. Chapter 6 of Mumford's book develops the basic theory of such group schemes (for example, they are commutative and the group structure is unique once the identity section is fixed).

Comment: thank you for the answer. This looks really like the kind of result I was hoping. Actually in my case I have a preferred zero-section (I'm dealing with a family of Jacobians). Which Mumford do you mean? I looked at Abelian Varieties but there I have only 4 chapters... (P.S.: there's a typo at the beginning: $B_a$ instead of $A_a$.)

Comment: Nice. In general this fails : let $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow B$ be any relative abelian variety (with the multiplication map over $B$ and the identity section). Now change the abelian variety structure on only one fiber by changing the identity using a translation. There won't be any identity section anymore, nor multiplication map.